# Using node subpath exports in Nuxt

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I have a local repo(called `repo-components`) with some vue components and a package.json where I want to implement [subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_subpath_exports), like so:

```
{
  "name": "repo-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Local repo",
  "exports": {
    "./components/": "./src/components/"
  },
}
```

I want to then use that repo inside a Nuxt project(let's call it `nuxt-project`) as a dependency, and then use subpath exports like so inside nuxt-project:

`import MyButton from 'repo-components/components/MyButton.vue'`

However, when I try to do that import inside `nuxt-project`, it's not recognizing the subpath export I defined and simply tries to go directly to that path I defined(which doesn't exist). But if I try to do `import MyButton from 'repo-components/src/components/MyButton.vue'` then that works.

And if I try to use `repo-components` inside a simple node project and use require instead of import, then the `exports` field works perfectly, so clearly I'm missing some sort of configuration inside the Nuxt project.

Any help?